# Prove that if $F: A \rightarrow B$ and $F^{-1}$ is a function, then $F$ is one-to-one

Tags: proof-writing, proof-verification

Prove that if $F: A \rightarrow B$ and $F^{-1}$ is a function, then $F$ is one-to-one

Proof: Suppose $F$ is not one-to-one. Then there exist $x_{1}, x_{2} \in A$ such that $F(x_{1}) = F(x_{2})$ where $x_{1} \neq x_{2}$. Now, at this point I'm stuck as to how I can arrive at a contradiction. Could someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f:A\to B$ and $f^{-1}$ is a function $\Rightarrow f^{-1}(f(x_1))=f^{-1}(f(x_2))$ $\Rightarrow x_1=x_2$ as desired.

Answer (score 1):

A function cannot be one-many. It is impossible that $x_1=x_2$ and $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$.

Comment: I think you mean one-to-many where you say many-one; there certainly are functions that are many-to-one.

Comment: Haha I did. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $F(x_1) = F(x_2)$. Now apply $F^{-1}$ to both sides to get $F^{-1}(F(x_1)) = x_1 = F^{-1}(F(x_2)) = x_2$. Hence $F$ is injective.

Comment: I was beaten to the punch, so i'll upvote :).

Comment: Back at you :-). ${}{}{}{}$